# PayPal-Java SDK/Credit card payment issue

Tags: java, paypal

My question is about the way how credit card payment is realized by PayPal API

Particularly I'd like to ask about this code snippet from GitHub:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/payments/servlet/PaymentWithCreditCardServlet.java

Credit card object is prepared, all necessary credentials are typed in, including the amount to be payed, sender's billing address and name, etc.

The only thing I cannot understand from this, is why there is no receiver specified ?

That's basically all

Comment: The API token is probably specific to the receiver.

Comment: @immibis you mean the one generated by this line: `String accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential("client ID", "client secret", sdkConfig).getAccessToken();`  ? but how is the receiver known out of client ID and client secret ?

Comment: yes, http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/authorization.html#client-id-client-secret-redirect-uri . And (I expect; I've never actually used the paypal API) the client ID identifies you on PayPal the same way your user ID (1556820; look at the URL of your profile page) identifies you on Stack Overflow, or the number 28166705 identifies this question

Comment: @immibis i think you misunderstood the question, i need to know whom to send the money to. there is no receiver ID specified in the code

Comment: Downvoted. Post the code snippet, not the link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not a Java dev -

The "receiver" is "your" (merchant) REST application (which is tied to your PayPal Account) you setup in the Developer Console. You [authenticate](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#authentication--headers) when making requests - in this specific case, you are sending a credit card for auth/capture in one step (aka [`sale`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/payments/servlet/PaymentWithCreditCardServlet.java#L141)).

So "you" (the authenticated App) are/is the "receiver".

Think of this process as the API Credentials in the PayPal Classic APIs. Hth....

---

Update:

> so you mean that the token belongs to "receiver", not "sender" ? as well as those client ID and client secret ? i thought they belong to sender

"You" - your app, is the sender (in Paypal's context). Your app *sends* payment information to Paypal for processing. To do that, PayPal must know "who" you are (which Paypal/merchant account/app) is sending the request.

What exactly are you referring to as "receiver" - maybe it's just terminology that's getting in the way?

---

Update 2:

> by *receiver* I mean the party that gets the charged amount

- "Receiver" == funds: **In this specific example/code you referenced**.Your app/you merchant account that made/sent the request (your app is sender and "receiver" per this definition).

  This is a standard "business"/merchant payment processing flow. Forget the tech/API, think about a POS in a restaurant. That POS (aka "app") will send card data (from swiping a physical credit card) to some processor it has an account at, using whatever protocols it  needs to communicate with that processor.

If you're actually looking for some "send money to someone" flow (not the code you referenced), [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/) is probably what you're looking for. This has a different meaning for "receiver" - aka "recipient(s) of funds". I don't actually use it, but it seems straightforward...

Hth..

Comment: so you mean that the token belongs to "receiver", not "sender" ? as well as those `client ID` and `client secret` ? i thought they belong to sender

Comment: by receiver I mean the party that gets the charged amount. in the sample I've posted in my question, the amount is 7 USD. where are they going to ? PayPal receives my payment information, fine, but how does PayPal know where that amount is supposed to go ? who's going to receive it ?

Comment: @mangusta PayPal sends the money to you because the app used one of your access tokens.

Comment: @immibis so the owner of the token (and client ID together with client secret) receives the money?

Comment: looks like it, but again, I've never even used the PayPal API

Comment: @mangusta Updated again...Hth..

Comment: @EdSF that's what i want to find out, which line(s) of code (in my first question) corresponds to "POS (aka "app") sending card data (from swiping a physical credit card) to some processor it has an account at"

Comment: @mangusta Then the code you referenced is one way to do it (`sale`)

Comment: I missed the fact that the app owner registers it on PayPal server and gets unique client_id/secret pair for his app, which he later uses to get access token. this access token is used to issue transactions to PayPal server, which loads the paid amount to app owner's PayPal balance. it was barely a terminology confusion between "sender" and "receiver" : ) I accept the answer